# is it possible to make one click fires two events or more by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, triggers

I am currently making a temporary download page for website visitor.

The page includes a form, after the visitor fills the form up, the site will take them to the pdf download page.

In the download page, there are some pdf files download links (I am just using a tag.). However, i wanna make a onclick event to those links, once they have been clicked, the page will refresh automatically or redirect to other pages.

```
<a href="/file.pdf" onClick="window.location.reload()">The File</a>
```

I have tried the jquery way as well.

```
<a href="/file.pdf" id="FileDownload">The File</a>
<script>
   $("#FileDownload").click(function(){
         location.reload();
   });
</script>
```

But all the them are not working. Do you masters have any good ideas about this, many thanks.

P.S. What if I wanna add a countdown after a file is being started download, and then do page reload when countdown finishes.

Looks like have asked several questions... Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: `windows` misspelled too

Comment: So you want the user to download the file, and then have the page reload?

Comment: @ddlshack, yes, download the file, and do the page reloading.

Comment: @vearutop. Thanks God he doesn't need to spell his name, it' just there... `:)`

Comment: @NewInAlbert: Why do you want to reload after downloading a file?

Comment: @Rocket, wanna take the visitor away from the download page.

Comment: Do you want to reload the page after the download has started, or after the download has completed?

Comment: @ddlshack: I don't think you can redirect after the download is done.  There's no way to detect the progress.

Comment: Lighttpd 2 has mod_progress which is like mod_upload_progress but for downloads too. Unfortunately theres no stable version of lighttpd 2 yet. http://demo.lighttpd.net/progress/

Comment: Also, if you send a cookie along with the download, that might get set after the download is complete.

Comment: @ddlshack, gee... i think it is too far for me, my problem is solved now. Thank you and Rocket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

http://jsbin.com/imikit/5

The timeout must be set to more than the response time of the server serving the file, otherwise the javascript won't fire. So set it to something high.

```
<a href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip" id="download">The File</a>

$('#download').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
  }, 1000);
});
```

Or

```
<a href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip" id="download" target="_blank">The File</a>

$('#download').click(function() {
  window.location = 'http://www.google.com/';
});
```

Most browsers will close the newly opened window once the download has initiated.

---

Lighttpd 2's [mod_upload](http://demo.lighttpd.net/progress/) might be worth looking at. Unfortunately there's no stable version of Lighttpd 2 yet.

---

You could try sending a cookie along with the download, then detecting it with javascript. This will either be set after the headers are sent, or after the body is sent. (test it)

Comment: i have tried your way, but it doesn't work. The active window is not the browser after clicking, the download dialog window has been opened up. Maybe that is the problem. Many thanks still!!!

Comment: firefox, can't see any reloading happens

Comment: Glad I could help. You can mark it as best solution by clicking the tick to the left of the post.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options for the `onClick` parameter:

1. Add semicolons between each line that can have one
2. Write a function to do all your tasks an have the `onClick` method call that.

Someone else might be able to help with the jQuery side, but it would be similar, I would think.

All of these methods will fire as many events as you like.

For the countdown, try the `setTimeout()` function.

EDIT: After seeing comments, try `<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank" onClick="window.location.reload()">Click Here</a>`. This will open the link in a popup window and reload the current one - you may need the setTimeout() for the reload so the link opens before the reload() event fires.

Comment: That's not really what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is open the download in a new window, then redirect the page.

```
<a href="/file.pdf" id="FileDownload">The File</a>
<script>
   $("#FileDownload").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       window.open(this.href);
       location.reload();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Not really work, maybe it is just impossible, the situation is after clicking the link, the download window has popped up, then the download page won't execute anything... But thank you all the same!!!

Comment: @NewInAlbert: Huh?  What's the problem?

Comment: The download page didn't reload after clicking the link. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure?  Check the console for errors?  Maybe it reloaded really fast :-P

Comment: can't find any errors. i have added the "target="_blank" into the a as well, but the page still has no reaction. Thanks

Comment: Ah, it works now, my module's code stopped it before!!! So many good answers! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a link the default action is to follow it and adding onClick code doesn't change that.

Try:
`onClick="windows.location.reload();return false;"`

This will solve the first part.

As for the second part (counter/redirect on download finish) use this plugin http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx to download the file and use successCallback to redirect:

```
$.fileDownload('/file.pdf', {
    successCallback: function () { 
         windows.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Comment: He wants file.pdf to be served to the user.

Comment: Gah, forgot Ajax request will not be able to open download prompt - updated answer.

Comment: Updated answer does work and it doesn't use any timeouts (which are an awful solution here as download times will vary) - it just fires reload the moment download finishes.

Comment: Yeah, I think I should forget the timeout stuffs.